# On Bootstrap how can I force the content to fit inside a specific column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On this project I'm working on, the user has the ability to decide which widgets (logo, search, sign in, cart button) are placed on this header up to a limit of 12 columns. They can decide how many columns each widget will take.

[image]

On this scenario, I have a widget that takes 2 bootstrap columns, but the entire content cannot fit inside.
I must have the whitespace set to 'nowrap', which is making the content overflowing to the next column.

**I would like to know if it's possible in CSS and how can I force the content of this column to expand and adapt to it's width when there's no room (maintaining the white-space set to 'nowrap').**

Below is a simplified version of the HTML used (that still produces the problem I'm trying to fix)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                        <a class="logo" href="#" style=""><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search All Categories">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 text-nowrap">
                        <a><span>Hi, Sign In<br><strong>Your Account</strong></span></a>
                        <a><span>Quick Order</span> <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                        <div class="cart-btn">
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the cart button

```
.cart-btn {
        width: 120px;
        height: 40px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #292c2e;
        margin-left: 10px;
}
```

A sample on JSFiddle reproducing this issue
http://jsfiddle.net/scottx/mA6Za/438/

The idea is to allow the user to add these widgets to the header and make sure that all will load as supposed and prevent them from 'breaking' regardless of what widgets were added and how many columns they decide to assign for each one. So in this scenario, a user added the widget 'logo' taking 2 columns, the widget 'search' taking 6 columns, the widget 'various' which contains the sign in button, favorites, etc and is taking 2 columns, and the widget 'cart' also taking 2 columns. The problem I'm facing here is that the widget 'various' on smaller screens is too large to fit in 2 columns only.

Probably what I'm trying to achieve is not possible in a way that if we're taking more space than assigned to a column, other column will have to lose space and I guess the browser doesn't know which one will be.
I think this can be fixed with JS but I'd like to know if anyone might have a solution with CSS only.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I agree with Dan Vinnicombe...without seeing the Code it's hard to say how to help you. As a person who works with Bootstrap every day I will say that I believe you solution isn't technical but compositional. You're bartering for room that you currently aren't allowing yourself. Something needs to change in order for you to have the space you need.

Comment: As mentioned in the existing 'answers', there's not much we can do without seeing your existing code

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
div.row > div > * {
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

This css will force all elements inside cols to take max. 100% width of parent

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve in there but we can make text to stop overflow container with

```
.text-nowrap {
  white-space:initial;
}
```

[Update JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mA6Za/442/)

Comment: I tried this but got no success, sorry Kejt. I added a sample on JSFiddle where we can see it happening. Thanks.

Comment: I update @Kejt answer and `fiddle` link also please go through that.

Comment: My pleasure @Kejt